# vuex. Can't get access to object variable

Tags: vue.js, object, vuex

look at my vuex code:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        article: {},
        slug: '',
    },
    actions: {
        getArticleData(context, payload) {
            axios.get('/api/article-json', { params: {slug:payload } }).then((response) =>{
                context.commit('setArticleData', response.data.data);
            });
        }
    },
    getters: {
        articleLikes(state) {
            return state.article.statistic.likes;
        },
        articleViews(state) {
            return state.article.statistic.views;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setArticleData(state, payload) {
            state.article = payload;
        },
        setCurrentSlug(state, payload) {
            state.slug = payload;
        },
        setCurrentStatistic(state, payload) {
            state.statistic = payload;
        }
    }
})
```

the code works like this - `getArticleData` action set Data in article object.
In create() hook set article opbject:

```
{
"id": 14,
"title": "Deserunt ea natus pariatur sunt eum voluptatem.",
"img": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/5F113B/FFFFFF/?text=LARAVEL:8.*",
"body": "  fugiat.",
"created_at": "1 месяц назад",
"comments": [
    {
        "id": 40,
        "subject": "Impedit inventore quis.",
        "body": "Qui rem ut beatae expedita nemo.",
        "created_at": "2 дня назад"
    },
    {
        "id": 41,
        "subject": "Nam et sit.",
        "body": "Dolor voluptas error eos quod.",
        "created_at": "2 дня назад"
    },
],
"tags": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Ut"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Fugiat"
    },
],
"statistic": 
    {
        "likes": 7,
        "views": 153
    }
}
```

This object formed by Laravel resource

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'img' => $this->img,
            'body' => $this->body,
            'created_at' => $this->createdAtForHumans(),
            'comments' => CommentResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('comments')),
            'tags' => TagResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('tags')),
            'statistic' => new StateResource($this->whenLoaded('state')),
        ];
    }
```

I can't get access to article.statistic.views and article.statistic.likes from getters.

In views component i have code

```
computed: {
        viewsNumber() {
            return this.$store.getters.articleViews;
        },
    }
```

and template

```
<template>
   <span class="badge bg-danger">{{viewsNumber}} <i class="far fa-eye"></i></span>
</template>
```

this is my console errors

```
app.js?id=80d6f0783c93a26b57e1:20787 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'views' of undefined"

found in

---> <ViewsComponent> at resources/js/components/ViewsComponent.vue
       <ArticleComponent> at resources/js/components/ArticleComponent.vue
         <Root>

app.js?id=80d6f0783c93a26b57e1:22054 TypeError: Cannot read property 'views' of undefined
```

for `comments` and `tags` no problems. In comments component i have access to comments^

```
computed: {
        article() {
            return this.$store.state.article;
        },
    },

<div v-for="comment in article.comments">
    <div class="toast showing" style="min-width: 100%;">
        <div class="toast-body">
            {{comment.body}}
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

What problem with `article.statistic.likes` and  `article.statistic.views`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is it cannot verify whether `views` or `likes` will be available in `articles.statistic`.
You are not ensuring where `articles.statistic` will be defined or not.

So the simple solution is do a check before accessing any child element of `articles.statistic`

e.g. You can redefine your method like -

```
....

getters: {
        articleLikes(state) {
            if(state.article.statistic){
                return state.article.statistic.likes;
            } else {
                return ...
            }
        },
        articleViews(state) {
            if(state.article.statistic){
                return state.article.statistic.views;
            } else {
                return ...
            }
        }
    },
....
```

Comment: Ok. one question. If i wan't get access without getters,in the likes-component i do computed property article() {this.$store.state.article;}, and i cant get access to  {{article.statistic.likes}}?

Comment: and second question - where i can read about this problem? maybe some documentation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question properly, but if you want to read more about the above problem you mentioned, you can check this - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties

It's not very clear but this basically says that since Vue doesn’t allow dynamically adding root-level reactive properties, you can either a type for your variable (i.e. for article and article.statistics) or you do a check on your own.

PS. Maybe this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794374/4868249
It explains how the variables in Vue are evaluated